# Will auto-encoder works for already extracted features

Tags: machine-learning, classification, deep-learning, feature-engineering, autoencoders

Currently, I am try to use auto-encoders based deep learning to perform some classification task. (In particular, I am a newbie and just used Matlab build-in functions instead of other more powerful packages).

Here are some Matlab examples. [Auto-encoders Example](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/training-a-deep-neural-network-for-digit-classification.html). However, it seems to me that auto-encoders work quite well with 'images' input, and the auto-encoders can also extract very nice features for further classification.

For my problem, I haven't got original images, but some calculated statistics attributions, for example, some already calculated mean, standard deviation, min, max and etc.

My question is that can I still use auto-encoders for this type of classification? For example, my input is not images, but extracted statistics attributions (in other word, already extracted features). Or I need to use the actual data before the calculation of the statistics, and let auto-encoders extracting features?

Comment: You can still use it, of course. But if the features you work on are coarse / irrelevant, the auto-encoder cannot do miracles...

Comment: @mic Thanks a lot for your reply. Could you be more specific about coarse/irrelevant features? Actually, the statistics (like mean and standard deviation) are always meaningful representation for the data, right? In another way to clarify this problem, in fact, I obtained good results using these features (mean, standard deviation etc) and SVM classifier. However, want to improve the accuracy by deep learning (auto-encoders). If these features work well with SVM, does that mean they are potentially good (not coarse or irrelevant) for auto-encoders?

Comment: "are always meaningful representation for the data, right?" I disagree. What about each means are the same? A feature is informative in general if there is some variance in it.

Comment: @mic Thanks a lot for your comments. Sure, they are not always useful. But in the case of I used them with SVM classifier, and turns out some reasonable classification results. Does that mean they are also meaningful for auto-encoders? I am trying to do some coding and test anyway. Thanks.